# Is there any way to manually set the frequency of dates on x axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot time series data in matplotlib. But the dates are not evenly spaced (See the image below). I want the dates on x axis to be evenly spaced. I can manually get the ticklabels and set the visibility of the unwanted ticklabels to false. But is there any other way of doing it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set a variable with data of your x axis dates `x=[date1,date2,...]` then add

```
ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels(x)
```

Comment: Good one ! But I am trying to gain control over how matplotlib puts datetime on the x axis.